# Cpanel Account Running Inside WordPress Hosting Website

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, whm, whmcs

We have started our own web hosting business, already have a monthly paying client, and now are advertising and growing the business. I have already consulted with a full stack developer on this, he said it could take "many weeks" to build. My question is, "I am using WordPress to run our website for our hosting business https://muleshed.com/ , and we are using WHM / Cpanel to host all of the Cpanel accounts, and may want to install WHMCS at some point. How can we FULLY integrate a users Cpanel experience INSIDE our WordPress site, so our front end menu system is always available to them as they work in Cpanel? Or at a minimum frame the Cpanel login screen inside our WordPress menu system? I think it's pretty obvious for anyone who ever signed up for hosting, most companies have a fully integrated site where it is all one experience and not just a WordPress site and a Cpanel account. Thank you for your time, Marc William White USN-RET, DAV, CEO [www.rewhiteconsulting.com](http://www.rewhiteconsulting.com)

This content was "merged" with my question by the Stack Overflow system automatically. >>> "I tried using the embed tag in WP, it did not work. I reached out to Cpanel support, they said it is not possible. I consulted with a full stack developer."

Comment: You present an interesting problem in specification. If you can figure out how to specify the integration you want to match the capabilities of existing WordPress plugins and cPanel / WHM integration APIs (like single signon) you probably will get a decent system at reasonable price. But if you say "I need thus and such a solution, here is my spec," a commercial software vendor will say "no" and an indy developer or integration team will say "expensive". Try asking your vendor about single signon.

Comment: Thank you. WHM / Cpanel company says there is no way this can be done, and they offer no contact information for any company who could build out the site for us. Yes, I am trying to save money here, and don't want to fork over $10,000.00 for anyone to custom build a site. I don't understand why so many people are struggling to understand what it is we are working on, you seem to get it. We want a fully integrated site, same as any other hosting business typically has. Having my clients "leave" my site to go to Cpanel is disjointed. Thank you so much! MW

Comment: Can anyone else help with this? Any ideas please?